# Linearly Independent Sets in Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

> A subset $X$ of an abelian group $F$ is said to be linearly independent if $n_1 x_1 + ... + n_k x_k$ always implies $n_i = 0$ for every $i$ (where $n_i \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $x_1,...,x_k$ are distinct elements in $X$.
>
> Problem: $X$ is linearly independent if and only if every nonzero element of the subgroup $\langle X \rangle$ may be written uniquely in the form $n_1 x_1 + ... n_k x_k$ ($n_i \in \Bbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, and $x_1,...,x_k \in X$ are distinct).

I will focus on the $\impliedby$ direction. Here is a solution I found online which I feel is erroneous:

> Given $\sum n_i x_i = \sum m_i x_i$, we get $\sum (n_i - m_i)x_i = 0$ If every element of $\langle X \rangle$ is the unique linearly combination of elements from $X$, then to begin with we know $n_i = m_i$ for each $i \in I$ Since $0 = \sum 0x_i$, it  follows any linear combination $\sum n_i x_i = 0$ forces $n_i = 0$ for all $i \in I$; therefore, $X$ is linearly independent.

This seems wrong. First, they are assuming that *every* element in $\langle X \rangle$, including the identity $0$, can be uniquely written as certain combination of elements in $X$; but this is not what the problem statement says. Second, it doesn't seem that we can infer that $n_i = 0$ for every $i$ from $\sum n_i x_i = \sum 0 x_i$, since $0$ can (possibly) be written in a variety of ways and we are *assuming* that $\sum n_i x_i$ is zero.

My thought was to do something like the following. Suppose every $x \in \langle X \rangle \setminus \{0\}$ can be uniquely represented in the manner already mentioned. Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be distinct, nonzero elements in $X$, and suppose $k_1 x_1 + ... + k_n x_n = 0$. If $k_n x_n \neq 0$, then $k_1 x_1 + ... k_{n-1} x_{n-1} = 0x_1 + ... 0x_{n-1} -k_n x_n$. If the RHS is zero, then we are done. If not, then we have two different representations of the same element, unless $n_i = 0$ for every $i$. Now, if $k_n x_n = 0$, then choose the next nonzero element.

This seems incorrect, too, and, as you may have noticed, I am implicitly assuming that every element has infinite order. What's going on? How do we prove the statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to demonstrate that if there's the unicity of combination (for nonzero elements) then the set is indipendent.
Well, assume that $\sum_{i=0}^n{\alpha_i x_i}=0$ with $x_i\in X$ all distinct by assumption and wlog we can assume $\alpha_0\neq 0$ (and - obviously for the unicity of combination- $x_0\neq 0$). Now we have $\langle X\rangle\ni-\alpha_0 x_0=\sum_{i=1}^n{\alpha_i x_i}$, two different combinations of elements of $X$ for an element of $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: Isn't this basically what I was hinting at in my post? How do you deal with the ostensibly implicit assumption that there are no elements of finite order?

Comment: However if $x\in X$, with $X$ indipendent set, $nx=mx$ hold only if $n=m$